# How can I write a unit test with streams, promises and pipes together?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, stream, mocha.js

My function is

```
exports.downloadFromBucket = function(fileKey) {
  const localPath = `${process.cwd()}/data/${fileKey}`

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const localFile = fs.createWriteStream(localPath)
    const awsStream = s3.getObject({
      Bucket: process.env.UPLOAD_BUCKET,
      Key: fileKey
    })
    .createReadStream()
    .on('error', (err) => {
      logger.info('Error downloading file', err)
      return reject(err)
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
      logger.info('Completed downloading')
      return resolve(localPath)
    })
    .pipe(localFile)
  })
}
```

How would I go about writing a unit test for this using `mocha` and `sinon`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the prettiest solution but assuming you want to mock `s3` and `fs` and test the `on('error')` and `on('finish')` behavior:

You could use a custom s3 mocking class, stub the original s3 and fs with sinon and trigger the events you want to test.

```
// Custom S3 Mocking Library
class S3MockLibrary {
  constructor() {
    this.events = {};
  }
  getObject(options) {
    return this;
  }
  createReadStream() {
    return this;
  }
  on(event, func) {
    this.events[event] = func;
    return this;
  }
  pipe(file) {
    return this;
  }
  emit(event, err) {
    this.events[event](err);
  }
}
```

Test on('finish')

```
it('should verify', async () => {
  const s3Mock = new S3MockLibrary();
  const fsStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'createWriteStream').returns('success');
  const s3Stub = sinon.stub(s3, 'getObject').returns(s3Mock);

  // Emit the finish event async
  setTimeout(() => {
    s3Mock.emit('finish');
  }, 0);
  const result = await downloadFromBucket('test');

  fsStub.restore();
  s3Stub.restore();

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(fsStub);
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3Stub);

  assert.equal(result, `${process.cwd()}/data/test`);
});
```

Test on('error)

```
it('should fail', async () => {
  const s3Mock = new S3MockLibrary();
  const fsStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'createWriteStream').returns('success');
  const s3Stub = sinon.stub(s3, 'getObject').returns(s3Mock);

  setTimeout(() => {
    s3Mock.emit('error', 'testError');
  }, 0);
  let error;
  await downloadFromBucket('test').catch((err) => {
    error = err;
  });

  fsStub.restore();
  s3Stub.restore();

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(fsStub);
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3Stub);

  assert.equal(error, 'testError');
});
```

Comment: I get an error: `     TypeError: s3.getObject(...).pipe is not a function`

Comment: Works in my test file. Are you using ```strict``` mode? Which node version do you use? I guess ```s3.getObject(...).pipe``` is ```undefined``` or ```null```?